# Batch file not executing the correct IF statement based off user input

Tags: batch-file, variables, if-statement, user-input

Whenever I give any input, the code always executes whatever code is inside the first IF statement. So if I type in *"console clear"* it will execute the code for *"console help"*.

```
:: USER INPUT
:user_input
SET /P _userInput = ">"
ECHO "%_userInput%"
GOTO :check_command

:: COMMANDS
:check_command
:: CONSOLE COMMANDS
IF /I "%_userInput%" EQU "console help" {
    GOTO :console_help
}
IF /I "%_userInput%" EQU "console clear" {
    GOTO :console_clear
}
```

Comment: What is following the `:check_command` block? is the `:console_help` block placed there? I guess execution falls into this section after both `if` conditions fail (due to wrong syntax)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead!

```bat
REM USER INPUT
:user_input
SET /P "_userInput=>"
ECHO "%_userInput%"
GOTO :check_command

REM COMMANDS
:check_command
REM CONSOLE COMMANDS
IF /I "%_userInput%"=="console help" (
    GOTO :console_help
)

IF /I "%_userInput%"=="console clear" (
    GOTO :console_clear
)
```

You were setting the variable:
_userInput<kbd>space</kbd>
so you would have had to use:
`ECHO "%_userInput %"`

Additionally you should have used parentheses `()` not braces, `{}` and `EQU` is more used for numeric comparisons, just using `==` is the more common usage.